# Photo Capture stream to SoftwareBitmap

Tags: c#, imaging

My Code:

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
ImageEncodingProperties properties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(properties, stream);
IBuffer buffer = new byte[stream.Size].AsBuffer();
await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
SoftwareBitmap sfbmp = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(buffer, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 4176, 3120); // Exception is thrown here
```

Exception:

> Insufficient memory for response

Honestly, I don't know anything about bitmap buffers so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by using BitmapDecoder

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
ImageEncodingProperties properties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(properties, stream);
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
SoftwareBitmap sfbmp = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
```